# How to pass an Element of DOM in xml to another activities

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression = "...";

EmParent = (Element) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(Doc,XPathConstants.NODE);

Intent intent = new Intent(com.FSC.xml.MainActivity.this,com.FSC.xml.FileForm.class);
intent.putExtra("Em", EmParent)

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please add more concrete description to the question

Comment: Hi . In my app I read data from a xml file and I save this into element EmParent . Then I want pass EmParent to another activity and use it

Comment: I dont know how can I do this

Comment: How does your class EmParent look? Can you share this code?

Comment: sorry but I read it as Element of DOOM and i cracked up.. carry on

Comment: ;-) ;-) yes its like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass nonParcelable or nonSerializable objects into the `Intent`. Here is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783528/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-dom-object-via-an-intent-and-parcelable).

But if you know structure of the `EmParent` class

**First**, you can create a wrapper class which will extend `Parcelable` or implement `Serializable` and converter method which converts `EmParent` into `EmParentWrapper` and then pass it into `intent`.

**Second**, is to put in the `intent` data from you element by names(of course if you know it)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("FirstAttr", element.getAttribute("FirstAttr"));
    intent.putExtra("SecondAttr", element.getAttribute("SecondAttr"));
```